# Brew update errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, homebrew

I'm trying to install Ruby/RVM/Rails on my Mac but I was unaware that I had to install Homebrew first.  Upon running the recommended `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"` to install, all that happened is `env` and `bash` ran alternating.

I followed https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation#untar-anywhere  <- these instructions on installing.  Downloaded and untar'd my files in /usr/local/ and symlinked them to /usr/bin/ and /usr/local/bin.

I then tried running `rvm get head` which succeeded, and `rvm requirements` which replied with

```
Installing requirements for osx/10.8/x86_64, might require sudo password
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
Cowardly refusing to continue at this prefix: /usr
Cowardly refusing to continue at this prefix: /usr
```

I tried running `brew update` and `Cowardly refusing to continue at this prefix: /usr` appears again.  I ran all these with `sudo` and same results.

Any help  would be much appreciated!  I would be willing to uninstall everything and start from scratch if someone could give me steps on doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another good guide here that covers more of the pre-requisites.

http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: Thanks, I was able to remove my `homebrew` installation by removing the folder and ran `rvm cleanup` and `rvm implode`  to remove my fudged installation of Ruby 2.0.0-p0.  Now following those instructions and they seem to be working